# Pattern rule with files in different directories?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following pattern rule that I wrote after some struggle

```
%.o : $(addprefix $(SRCDIR),$(notdir $(@:.o=.f90)))
        $(COMPILE) $(addprefix $(SRCDIR),$(notdir $(@:.o=.f90))) -o $@
```

`SRCDIR` is where the corresponding source code files are found. Object files and source code files are in separate directories and the object file names contain their path. So, for each object file, the source code file name is obtained by text substitution and prefixed with `SRCDIR`.

How can I do this more concisely?

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your question is slightly unclear, but perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.f90
    $(COMPILE) $< -o $@
```

Comment: That's precisely it! I can't believe why was I overcomplicating this like that. Thank you very much.